# Lost my 3d Manipulator

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Lost my 3d Manipulator in my current session.

Things I've tried, ctrl space, checked snap, and reset to factory settings still nothing.

Started a new blend and the 3d Manipulator is present.

Using 2.79a on a higher end Windows 10 laptop.

tia

Comment: [Edit] your question and show screenshot of full 3d viewport window, with its footer and object selected.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the 3D viewport, there are these buttons.

[image]

You probably don't see the manipulator wigit type buttons, so click on the button that's got the axies icon. Then, you can see the others, and choose which one you want.

Comment: Thanks, it's not the wigit buttons. That was my first goto since I've toggled these before. It's only with the blend I'm working on now. Plus I checked and getting same results on my desktop as with my laptop. I think I pressed some weird key combo but I don't know what.